# Highlighting radio button for selected team, disabling radio button for unavailable team

Tags: php, sql

To preface, I have four tables: nflteams, picks, users and schedule. I have this code to display a week's schedule from the nflteams and schedule tables:

```
 $scheduleTable = $db->query("SELECT s.gameid, a.teamname as awayteam, h.teamname 
 as hometeam, h.teamid as hteamid, a.teamid as ateamid FROM schedule as s

 LEFT JOIN nflteams as a ON s.awayid=a.teamid                                           
 LEFT JOIN nflteams as h ON s.homeid=h.teamid
 WHERE weekID='$week'")
```

Where I'm getting stuck, however, is also finding a way to make teams available and unavailable based on the user that is logged in (info stored in the users table) and the picks that user has made in past weeks (picks are stored in the picks table).

I have radio buttons set up so that they can be selected and submitted, allowing a user to select a team as their "pick" for the week. I'm just not sure how to pull the user and picks tables in to enable/disable the radio buttons. I tried to do a loop within a loop but I didn't have any luck getting it to work.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some example data of how it is now and how you did like to have the data. Plus if it is on fiddle. Also, I'm not sure if your problem is conserning sql or php, because if it is PHP you should put relevant code for the printing part of the radio buttons.

Comment: Sure, @jorge-campos here's the code I have for the radio buttons:

`<?php
while ($scheduleRow = $scheduleTable->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="pick" value="<?=$scheduleRow['ateamid']?>" id="<?=$scheduleRow['gameid']?>-1" onclick="javascript: submit()"> 
<label for="<?=$scheduleRow['gameid']?>-1"><?=$scheduleRow['awayteam']?></label> at 
<input type="radio" name="pick" value="<?=$scheduleRow['hteamid']?>" id="<?=$scheduleRow['gameid']?>-2" onclick="javascript: submit()"> 
<label for="<?=$scheduleRow['gameid']?>-2"><?=$scheduleRow['hometeam']?></label>
<?php
}
?>`

Comment: Nailed it after some playing around -- brought a second SQL query into the mix and stored its contents in an array, then did a foreach loop to loop over all the picks and compare them to team ids on the schedule.

Comment: You should edit your question with this code and add your answer as you figured out by yourself.